# Copy ranges and multiply in loop

Tags: excel, vba

Ive been searching left and right but seem to only find bits and pieces. i'm unable to combine these into the solution i need. 
My workbook has a list of items on the first sheet, the partnumbers in column A have to be searched for in Column A of a second sheet and if they exist there, those rows need to be copied to a third sheet.In steps i'm looking to do the following:

- Column A of sheet1 (called "input") has several partnumbers.
- After clicking CommandButton2 on sheet1, all partnumbers in Column A (starting in cell A5)should be searched for in Column A of sheet3 (called "partlists", starting in A2).
- If found here, for all the respective rows where the partnumbers match: columns C to G("partlists") should be copied to sheet2("picklist") column A below the last row, the value in column E("picklist") has to be multiplied with the value in Column E("input") AND columns G to K("input") copied to the respective rows column G("Picklist")
- If not found on "partlists", copy entire row from "input" to "picklist" below last row.

So far i've got the following code:

```
Sub InputPickMatch()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, lngNextRow As Long, LookUpListInput As Range, LookUpListParts As Range

Set LookUpListInput = Sheets("Input").Range("A:A") 'lookup list Input
Set LookUpListParts = Sheets("Partlists").Range("A:A")

With Sheets("Input")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row
        For i = 5 To LR
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListParts, 0)) Then
            .Range(Cells(i, "A").Address(), Cells(i, "D").Address()).Copy
            Sheets("Picklist").Select
            lngNextRow = Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & lngNextRow).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Range(Cells(i, "F").Address(), Cells(i, "K").Address()).Copy
            Sheets("Picklist").Range("E" & lngNextRow).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
    Next i
End With

With Sheets("Partlists")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row
        For i = 3 To LR
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListInput, 0)) Then
            .Range(Cells(i, "C").Address(), Cells(i, "G").Address()).Copy
            Sheets("Picklist").Select
            lngNextRow = Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & lngNextRow).PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=xlPasteValues
            'Sheets("Picklist").Cells(lngNextRow, "E") = Sheets("Input").Cells(LookUpListInput, "E") * .Cells(i, "G") 'NOT WORKING: Multiply row from lookuplist column E with .Cells(i, "G")
            'Sheets("Input").Range(Cells(LookUpList, "G").Address(), Cells(LookUpListInput, "K").Address()).Copy      'NOT WORKING: Copy row from lookuplist column G:K
            'Sheets("Picklist").Range("F" & lngNextRow).PasteSpecial                                             'Paste Picklist column G
            End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

It's working ok up to where i try to multiply and copy from the lookup list.

Hopefully someone can help

Comment: What happens when you try to copy? Do you see an error? If so, what is the error? **Hint**: you don't need the `Select` statements. Code will work without selecting the sheet you want to interact with

Comment: It gives error 13 type mismatch (the latter translated from dutch so hope it makes sense)

Comment: Have a look at `resize` option in VBA. I think that should resolve your issue

Comment: Here is some info on [avoiding select in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). If you are only going to copy/paste values, you may as well assign the values from one range to another. ex.: `Range("A2").value = Range("A1").value`

Comment: I think the issue is that is use LookUpListInput (which is dimmed as range) to point to the row on the "input" sheet where the match has been found. How can i get the result (row number) of the Application.Match?

Comment: @ cybernetic.nomad Tried your suggestion, seems to be much smoother. Thanks

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - event better when many cells are "selected" with `Range("A2").Resize(10,1).Value = Range("G2").Resize(10,1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

I got it guys

```
Sub InputToPicklist()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, lngNextRow As Long, LookUpListInput As Range, LookUpListParts As Range
Dim Matchres As Variant

Set LookUpListInput = Sheets("Input").Range("A:A")
Set LookUpListParts = Sheets("Partlists").Range("A:A")

With Sheets("Input")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 5 To LR
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListParts, 0)) Then
             lngNextRow = Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
             Sheets("Picklist").Range(Cells(lngNextRow, "A").Address(), Cells(lngNextRow, "D").Address()).Value = .Range(Cells(i, "A").Address(), Cells(i, "D").Address()).Value
             Sheets("Picklist").Range(Cells(lngNextRow, "E").Address(), Cells(lngNextRow, "J").Address()).Value = .Range(Cells(i, "F").Address(), Cells(i, "K").Address()).Value
             End If
    Next i
End With

With Sheets("Partlists")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'last row
        For i = 3 To LR
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListInput, 0)) Then
            lngNextRow = Sheets("Picklist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Picklist").Range(Cells(lngNextRow, "A").Address(), Cells(lngNextRow, "E").Address()).Value = .Range(Cells(i, "C").Address(), Cells(i, "G").Address()).Value
            Matchres = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListInput, 0)
            Sheets("Picklist").Cells(lngNextRow, "E") = Sheets("Input").Cells(Matchres, "F") * .Cells(i, "G")    'Multiply row from lookuplist column E with .Cells(i, "G")
            Sheets("Picklist").Range(Cells(lngNextRow, "F").Address(), Cells(lngNextRow, "J").Address()).Value = Sheets("Input").Range(Cells(Matchres, "G").Address(), Cells(Matchres, "K").Address()).Value     'Copy row from lookuplist column G:K

            End If
    Next i
End With

Sheets("Input").Range("A5:K138").ClearContents

End Sub
```

First

```
Dim Matchres As Variant
```

and calling it

```
Matchres = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookUpListInput, 0)
```

Does the trick